# Laravel sortBy multiple values and multiple keys

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

I'm trying to figure out the best way to sort by multiple values and multiple keys at once.

I have the following "sort sequence";

1. sort by "finished or not"
2. sort by "out of time or not"
3. sort by "points in total"
4. sort by "points for your time"
5. sort by "points for each 'secret time control', can be null, then you end up at the end of that sorting"
6. sort by "the distance driven"

I currently have something like this of response (sorted);

```
[
    {
        "team_number": 201,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": {
            "tc_start": 0,
            "tc_round_in": 0,
            "tc_stop": 0
        },
        "points_for_gtc": 1,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": [
            0,
            1
        ],
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 100,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": false,
        "total": 101
    },
    {
        "team_number": 202,
        "points_for_time": 2,
        "detail_points_for_time": {
            "tc_start": 0,
            "tc_round_in": 0,
            "tc_stop": 2
        },
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": [],
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 100,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": false,
        "total": 102
    },
    {
        "team_number": 203,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "team_number": 204,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "team_number": 205,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "team_number": 206,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "team_number": 207,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "team_number": 208,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "team_number": 209,
        "points_for_time": 0,
        "detail_points_for_time": 0,
        "points_for_gtc": 0,
        "detail_points_for_gtc": 0,
        "points_for_distance": 0,
        "missed_controls": 0,
        "out_of_time": false,
        "dnf": true,
        "total": 0
    }
]
```

So the goal here is, that I get a full sorting based on the above "sequence".

I currentmy use this;

```
$results = $results->sortBy('total')
    ->sortBy('points_for_time')
    ->sortBy('points_for_gtc') // this is an issue, since it puts you below someone else when you have less points
    ->sortBy('points_for_distance')
    ->sortBy('out_of_time')
    ->sortBy('dnf');
```

There is another "field" I have, `detail_points_for_gtc`, which holds the points (in order) for each "time control".

The possibility exists that there is nothing filled in, if so, then you should be at the end of the list. it's also possible that the value is null. Then it should be sorted at the end.

I have no idea on how I can sort on the `detail_points_for_gtc`, and if this sorting is "the correct sorting"?

Anyone who understands the question and may be able to help?

Comment: How do you want to compare two `detail_points_for_gtc`, assuming they are not null and not empty?

Comment: It should be "compared" as the following: looping over all the items with their order respected. And then, it should be sorted from lowest to highest

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this;

```
// you can send column and direction from request or where you need
$results = $request->direction == 'asc' ? $results->sortBy($request->column) : $results->sortByDesc($request->column);
```